# How change background color in block

Tags: jquery

http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_47760/

Hi guys. How I can do this. You see this blocks. I want do as there? Help.Thank`s

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: CTRL+U in most modern browsers will help.

Comment: Shomz - This site does not show the code.I know a little about Jquery but it will not be able to realize

Comment: I've posted an answer which requires no jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/lJucw/) (jsFiddle wont work for me at the moment).

HTML:

```
<div>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
div{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  position:relative;
  background:black;
  margin:0;
}

p{
  position:absolute;
  top:125px;
  left:125px;
  width:0;
  height:0;
  background:red;
  transition:.5s;
}

div:hover p{
  height:250px;
  width:250px;
  top:0;
  left:0;

}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks. how could I forget about transition:.5s. Big thanks

Comment: Make sure you use `-webkit-transition:` and `-moz-transition:` also for `webkit` and `moz` browsers!